# append function not working for DataFrame

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, append, python-3.6

I am trying to append the data frame in the different list to different data frame but each time the same data frame is only appending after on time

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = [],[],[],[]
def conFile(file,df):
    name=file.split('/')[-1]
    print(name) #to check condition
    if name=='xyz':
       list1.append(df)
       print(df)
    if name=='abc':
       list2.append(df)
       print(df)
    if name=='mno':
       list3.append(df)
       print(df)
    if name=='kmno':
       list4.append(df)
       print(df) 

files=glob.glob('path')
for file in files: 
    df=pd.read_csv(file)
    conFile(file,df)
```

this script is working fine for xyz and abc but not working for condition mno and kmno. Actually the same list 2 copies in both list3 and list4 instead of different dataframe.
I also check datafarme coming is different each time but in list3 and list4 always the same datafarme is repeated. I also check the condition each time and each time condition is also matching but why such thing happens I am not able to understand. If anyone faces this issue earlier can please help on this part

Answer (score 0):

your list init seems to be wrong:

if you do like this:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = ([], ) * 4
```

the same appended values is copied everywhere.

instead do initialize lists like this:

```
list1, list2, list3, list4 = [], [], [], []
```

Comment: list1, list2, list3, list4 = [], [], [], [] even for this format also issue remain same

Comment: @Rishav Unless you share the filename or little more info, its hard to tell on whats going on. Also why you have dot there ? `name=file.split('/').[-1]`

Comment: Actually, I am fetching filename form filepath and store it in name variable. then comparing file name and appending dataframe into the list

Comment: you understand this problem ?